# Calculating average of specific lines in an array and storing in another array

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to calculate the average of specific lines in an array.
For example the format of the array looks like this:

```
float Array[20] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,...20}
```

I want to calculate the average of the first 5 numbers in the array, then the average of the next 5 numbers and so on... storing them into another array with only the averages of those numbers.

Here's my code so far

```
float average_values[4];
for (int a = 0; a < 4; a++){    //20 elements in array divided by 5 = 4
    float sum = 0;
    for (int b = 0; b < (20 / 4); b++){
        sum = sum + scores[b];
    }
    average_values[i] = sum / (20 / 4);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
        int scores[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20};
        float average_values[4];
        for (int a = 0; a < 4; a++)
        {    //20 elements in array divided by 5 = 4
            float sum = 0;
            for (int b = 0; b < (20 / 4); b++)
                sum = sum + scores[b+a*5]; // THIS IS THE BIT YOU'D MISSED
            average_values[a] = sum / (20 / 4);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keeping aside all typos in your current post

I assume you have trouble in filling up your `average_values` array.

So assume `scores` array as matrix for 5 columns and 4 rows,

So your inner loop should look like:

```
for (int b = 0; b < 5; b++){
    sum = sum + scores[ a*5 + b];
                      //~~~ Correct index for next sets
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), it would be:

```
auto means = Array
             | ranges::view::chunk(5)
             | ranges::view::transform([](auto&& r) { return ranges::accumulate(r, 0.f) / 5; });
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f1e44c0f622cd133)